# html h1 text is hidden under div

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

In my div I am trying to get the h1 text to show, but the div only shows the button

```css
#sidebar {
  background-color: #13617C;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class=row>
  <div class="col-lg-3" id="sidebar">
    <button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo">Collapsible</button>
    <div id="demo" class="collapse">
      <h1>HEllo Worlds</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="map" class="col-lg-9"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please create a [mcve]

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example  and also, please try changing the color of the text to something like white  in the CSS and see if that works

Comment: I edited your question. I've formatted your code into SO snippet. Then, I found an error : after the closing tag for your wrapper `<div class="row">...</div>>`. In fact, you had an extra `>` which could cause errors. Then, be sure to import Jquery, as bootstrap < 4 needs it. Then, clicking the button will unfold your `<div id="demo"`, and showing your title :)

Comment: On button click  it is showing. if you want to show without click then remove class collapse from div.